# Passing Unix Variable to psql date_part function

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, unix, psql

Here is my Script:

```
export Year=$(echo `date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"` | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F "-" '{print $3}')  
export Day=$(echo `date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"` | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F "-" '{print $2}')
export Month=$(echo `date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"` | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F "-" '{print $1}')
export Hour=$(echo `date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"` | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')

  #Output of exports
  #Year 2017
  #Day 04
  #Month 10
  #Hour 05

psql -U postgres -d dbname -t -c "select id, time, code, level, message, trace  from logarchive where date_part('year',log_time) = \"$Year\" and date_part('month',log_time) = \"$Month\" and date_part('day',log_time) = \"$Day\" and date_part('hour',log_time) = \"$Hour\" and log_level = 'ERROR' limit 5;" > /tmp/List.txt
```

The Error i am getting:

> [root]# sh new.sh ERROR:  column "2017" does not exist LINE 1: ...om
>   log_archive where date_part('year',log_time) = "2017" and...

When i try to do it manually without variablesi get the desired results.

Please help.

Comment: BTW `read Year Month Day Hour <<< $(date +"%Y %m %d %H")` would be shorter a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes (`"`) denote an identifier. Just remove them and use bare numbers and you should be fine:

```
psql -U postgres -d dbname -t -c "select id, time, code, level, message, trace  from logarchive where date_part('year',log_time) = $Year and date_part('month',log_time) = $Month and date_part('day',log_time) = $Day and date_part('hour',log_time) = $Hour and log_level = 'ERROR' limit 5;" > /tmp/List.txt
```